# Output all 'findbyattributes' in yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii, find

I have a `findByAttributes` in yii and I was wondering how you output all of the data that meets the criteria specified

I have an example below:

Assuming that in my `Test` table I have 3 rows which has the value `1` in `test1` attribute then I have this code in my view

```
$a= Test::model()->findByAttributes(array('test1'=> '1'));
$b= $a-> id;
print_r($b);
```

I've noticed that this code would print the id '1' instead of '1 2 3'.

What code can I use so that it would output ALL of the ids with 1 in their `test1` attribute?

sorry for the beginner question. I hope anyone can help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all records you have to use method findAllByAttributes (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes-detail) instead of findByAttributes. Method findAllByAttributes will return all rows which meets requirements, then you should iterate over it to get an id.

Example,

```
foreach( $models as $model) { 
    print_r($model->id);
}
```

But if you want to get only ids it is better tou use CDbCommand and querycolumn

```
Yii::app()->db
->createCommand()
->select('id')
->from('Test')
->where('test1=:value', array(':value'=> 1))
->queryColumn()
```

It will return an array of ids

Comment: I see. thank you for the answer... but how do I get a single attribute... like in the example above I have the `$b= $a-> id;` can you please give an example?

Answer (score 1):

For retrive all the rows the meet a specific criteria you can use

```
 findAllByAttributes();
```

And for obtain  all the result you must loop eg ever this result:

```
$a= Test::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('test1'=> '1'));

foreach($a as $key => $value)  {

 echo $value->id
}
```